# rearranging data frame by two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I arrange data frame by decreasing order of values in column `value` where values in column `"cat"=X`

ex. data frame

```
df1<-data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),each=2), cat=rep(c("X", "Y"),4), value=c(1,0.6,1,0.5,1,2,1,5))
```

ex. rearranged data frame (that I want to see):

[image]

I tried     `df1[with(df1, order(-value, cat)),]`    after reviewing the first answer on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns), but it did not work, the result is below:

[image]

As you can see the two tables look different. I tried arrange command from `dplyr` package too but every result looks like the one above.

Thank you

Comment: @pyll The only piece missing from the dupe is that the OP needs to reorder the levels of the factor `group`, i.e. `df1$group <- factor(df1$group,levels = c('D','C','A','B'))`. Then the solutions there work just fine. I think your answer is a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `value` for `cat'x'` is always the same, we can sum the `value` by `group` and then use that to order the data.

```
# Create data.frame
df1<-data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B",   "C", "D"),each=2), 
                cat=rep(c("X", "Y"),4), 
                value=c(1,0.6,1,0.5,1,2,1,5))
# Sum values by group (since x is same...)
df2 <- aggregate(df1$value,   by=list(group=df1$group), FUN=sum)

# Join tables
library(plyr)
output <- join(df1, df2, by='group', type='left', match='all')

# Sort
output <- output[with(output, order(-x, cat)),]
```

Or another (possibly better) way involves designating the factor levels.  They are set alphabetically by default, but you can set them based on the order of their `value`

```
# Limit to only cat=Y
df2 <- df1[which(df1$cat=='Y'),]

# Order by descending
df2 <- df2[order(-df2$value),]

# Create a vector based on group column
order_vector <- df2[,'group']

# Use vector from above to designate new factor levels
df1$group <- factor(df1$group, levels = order_vector)

# Sort
output2 <- df1[with(df1, order(group, cat)), ]
```